# Set <select> element depending on another <select> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I need a select element's options to change depending on the value of another.

```
<select id="first">
    <option value="1">one</option> // When you click this one, all the values of #second change (arbitrary number of entries)
    <option value="2">two</option> // When you click this one, all the values of #second change to something else (not necessarily the same number)
</select>
<select id="second">
    <option value="thisChanges">soDoesThis</option>
    <option value="thisToo">andThis</option>
</select>

<script>
    $("#first").on("change", function() {
        <pseudo>
            if #first == "1"
                #second = {"this", "that", "the other"}
            else if #first == "2"
                #second = {"more", "even more", "yet another", "still more"}
        </pseudo>
    }
</script>
```

---

This is pretty much what I'm after (took me years to figure out how to completely replace the values of a select box), but the button click event doesn't even work. It was working a minute ago, although the for loop was not.

Obviously for my use case I would check if the select is clicked and retrieve its value with `.val()`, but I figured this button is easier for debugging.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6L0anpqf/7/)

HTML:

```
<select id="sel">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<button>
Click me
</button>
```

JS:

```
var list = ['11', 'Eleven', '12', 'Twelve', '13', 'Thirteen'];
$('button').on('click', function () {
        alert('click');
    var sel = $('#sel');
    alert('1');
    sel.empty();
    alert('2');
    for (i = 0, i < list.length; i+2) {
        $('#sel').append('<option value="' + list[i] + '">' + list[i+1] + '</option>');
    }
    alert('3');
});
```

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/x5PKf/2559/) ?

Comment: What is the expected output for the second element based on your first one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you specified jQuery, I'll give you a jQuery answer! Grab the value and the text from the selected option, and append a new one to the select:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#two', function() {
  var option_to_add = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
  var number_of_options = $('#two option').length
  $('#one').append($('<option>', {
    value: number_of_options,
    text: option_to_add
  }));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="one">
    <option value="cash">Cash</option>
    <option value="money">Money</option>
</select>
<select id="two">
    <option value="stack">Stack</option>
    <option value="overflow">Overflow</option>
    <option value="my">My</option>
    <option value="question">Question</option>
    <option value="op1">Should be option 1: <a id="option1"></a></option>
</select> Should also be option 1:
<div id="option1"></div>
```

Based on your comments and changes to your post, if you *just* want to replace the options in a select element using a dummy array (or array of arrays,) you can do so the following way *see code comments for details*:

```js
// dummy data array of arrays
var list = [
  [11, "Eleven"],
  [12, "Twelve"],
  [13, "Thirteen"]
];

// click the button, replace the select contents
$('#btn').on('click', function() {

  // build an array of option objects from an array of arrays
  // see below
  var opt_array = build_opt_array(list);

  $('#sel').empty();

  // add the new options
  $(opt_array).each(function(index) {
    $('#sel').append(opt_array[index]);
  });

});

// helper function
// builds a new array of option html objects from 
// an array of arrays
function build_opt_array(items) {
  var opt_array = [];
  $(items).each(function(index) {
    var new_option = $('<option>', {
      value: items[index][0],
      text: items[index][1]
    });
    opt_array.push(new_option);
  });
  return opt_array;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>

<button id="btn">
  Click me
</button>
```

Comment: @Sinjai - you need to clarify your edit to explain your problem a bit more transparently. When `#one` is selected, you want that value removed from one and placed in `#two`? [Do you want them to swap values?](http://jsfiddle.net/wahwahwah/x5PKf/2578/)

Comment: @Sinjai - this is pretty trivial with jQuery, it'd be great if you cleaned up your question edits using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) criteria, in case it might helps someone else down the road.

Comment: I'll edit it shortly. Can you be specific about what you don't understand? I think the part in italics sums it up the best. Say you have 3 sets of data. The first selects which set, the second displays the set.

Comment: @Sinjai - From what I gather, you're taking collections of values from a database, passing them to your view and then wanting to display a different collection as a `select` option (select 2) based on what is initially selected in "select 1" ... is this correct? On SO, you need to provide an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and *any* relevant code that you've tried, as well as a clear description of *the problem* you are facing.

Comment: Wish I could move this to chat. @wahwahwah I don't see how that would benefit anyone, other than making the problem more complicated. Super specific is good except it's, well, super specific. Someone looking to do this in the future would want to adapt this core concept to their needs.

Comment: @Sinjai - this site isn't a code writing service or tutorial service. Since you've changed your question, the jQuery / javascript answer is trivial. However, based on your comments and the nature of your original post, it seems to me that you are looking for a full working example of how to call data from your controller action, and display it within your view in a select list - based on a previously selected option. Which, is totally OK, but you need to show what you've tried. There are numerous examples already on this site that provide you with the basis for what you need.

Comment: Yeah, ultimately that's what I'm trying to do, but at this point I figured I'd just make another question for that and simplify this one. I still haven't found an answer to my trivial question. I've updated the question to reflect what I've tried.

Comment: And just to be clear, I don't think I quite knew what my problem was when I began, hence the several changes to my question. Posting this helped me with that.

Comment: @Sinjai -  Well, I'm glad to hear that there's been some help provided! I've updated my answer to include the jQuery needed to replace a select options.  Doing a project like it seems like you are is a great way to learn, and SO is a great place to help with that, the community really responds better to "atomic" questions (MVCE) and there's the added benefit of getting site rep per question that is deemed "a good one." Happy hunting!

Comment: MVCE is easier said than done, I've found! I kept it in mind, but even now I'm sure the question could be improved (assuming its basis has any merit at all), despite my best efforts.

Comment: I'm still not sure what's wrong with my code, though.

Comment: I'd like to mark this as the answer, but I still can't tell what distinguishes it from my own code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you requirement similiar to the cascading dropdownlist, if i have understood correctly.

Ex jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#state").prop("disabled", true);
  $("#country").change(function () {
    if ($("#country").val() != "Please select") {
       var options = {};
       options.url = "/home/getstates";
       options.type = "POST";
       options.data = JSON.stringify({ country: $("#country").val() });
       options.dataType = "json";
       options.contentType = "application/json";
       options.success = function (states) {
       $("#state").empty();
       for (var i = 0; i < states.length; i++) {
         $("#state").append("<option>" + states[i] + "</option>");
       }
       $("#state").prop("disabled", false);
    };
    options.error = function () { alert("Error retrieving states!"); };
    $.ajax(options);
  }
  else {
    $("#state").empty();
    $("#state").prop("disabled", true);
  }
 });
});
```

Kindly refer this good article for the complete code:

http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/b58fde6b-415e-454d-985b-d5dc4ad2fca8.aspx

Hope it will helps

Thanks

Karthik

Answer (score 0):

To get the text found in the first Select field, use the `.text()` function after using `find(":selected")` on your desired select field.

```
 $("#two").focus(function() {
    document.getElementById("option1").innerHTML = $("#one").find(":selected").text();
});
```